# mysql query with lots of conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I realise this is probably an absolutely horrible way to do a query, and of course its not working. The point of it is to select users based on a date range and a keyword.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE my_regdate BETWEEN '$ftimestamp' AND '$ttimestamp' AND my_username LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR my_realname LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR my_email LIKE '%$trimmed%' ORDER BY my_id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the brackets in the query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE my_regdate BETWEEN '$ftimestamp' AND '$ttimestamp' AND (my_username LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR my_realname LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR my_email LIKE '%$trimmed%') ORDER BY my_id");
```

Comment: @Gary I wouldn't use string interpolation ($ftimestamp, $ttimestamp), as it's subject to SQL injection,  you may want to consider using PDO so you can use placeholders. You can find all this information in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error() to print the error.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM my_users WHERE my_regdate BETWEEN '$ftimestamp' AND '$ttimestamp' AND my_username LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR my_realname LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR my_email LIKE '%$trimmed%' ORDER BY my_id";
$res= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```